# Rails 4 and Rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I've upgraded my rails 3 to rails 4. After I changed Gemfile, routes and other stuff I was able to run the server and navigate to the pages like I was have.

However, when running the specs I was get the same error messages:
**undefined method `respond_to' for xxxController.**

Do I need to update something on RSpec gem or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the example/test code at the point of failure?

Comment: `respond_to` is a basic RSpec matcher, unrelated to Rails, so it doesn't depend on the version of Rails you're using.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin isn't it? very strange behavior.

Comment: Can you share your test code?

Comment: It's a simple spec that uses "get :index" passing in the format. If a comment out this spec, I get the same error in another one. When I switch to another branch (using rails 3) it works fine again.

Comment: What matters is how `respond_to` is used and the surrounding code. Did you change RSpec versions as part of your Rails upgrade?

Comment: No, it hasn't change rspec version.

Comment: Figured it out. There was a configuration on my enviroments/test.rb set 'eager_load = false'. After removing this line it started to work again